# how to write libraries without forcing users to use the library's IOC container

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

The short question is:
Given a library *warrants* using a particular IOC container for its internals, when an application consumes that library, given the app *warrants* using an IOC container for wiring its dependencies, given if the the two containers are different, how can they play well together?

The scenario is, the application has classes defined that depend on types from the library. So when the application container attempts to build such a class, it needs to know how to resolve the type that lives in the library.

Here's the long winded question:

This question does seem to have been asked in different shapes and form before on SO, but I can't seem to find the answer I need so I am going to have a go at it with a hypothetical _over_simplified_ concrete example.
We want to write a library for logging that users can include as a package in their solution to get logging functionality out of the box. 
The public interfaces the library exposes are..

`public interface ILogger {}`

`public interface ITarget {}`

Concrete implementations are

`internal class Logger: ILogger { public Logger(ITarget target) {}}`

`internal class FileTarget : ITarget {}`

Requirements are if the user includes our package and defines a class with a property of type `ILogger` or has a ctor argument of type `ILogger` then our library is responsible for injecting a concrete implementation for that interface into the user defined class. By default that injected logger will go to the file system for logging because the default implementation of an `ITarget` injected into the `ILogger` implementation is a `FileTarget` by our library.

If the user decides to write a class implementing the `ITarget` interface then our library will use that to inject into the `Logger` class and not use its default `FileTarget` implementation.

SO what I wish to demonstrate, is their is a bi-directional dependency here.

1. Our library depends on the user's assemblies, since it needs to scan the user's assemblies to load any extension points (i.e. an `ITarget` implementation) and inject those into its own objects ahead of any default implementations.
2. The user's assemblies depends on the library, since if the user chooses to define a class with an `ILogger` interface as a dependency, then that user object should get a concrete reference to that interface provided at runtime by our library.

The easy solution is if the user and our library are both using the same IOC container, then problem is solved. But this is a strong assumption. What I wish to do is

1. Use an IOC container with the library that caters best to the library's requirement, in my case its Ninject.
2. At run time somehow provide a mechanism for the user to call via some API into my library that will ensure Ninject is fired up and it scans the user's assemblies, and wires everything taking into account all extension points.

So far so good, its perfectly achievable, but here comes the tricky part.

- if the user is also using Ninject, then problem automatically solved, since Ninject already knows how to resolve Interfaces living in our library. But what if the user decides to use his/her choice of IOC container?

I almost want to define some sort of child container functionality in the library with an interface like such

`public interface IDependencyResolvingModule { T Get<T>(); []T GetAll<T>(); }`

and provide an implementation that uses our library's choice of container (i.e. Ninect) to resolve the type requested in the two methods define above.

I want the user's IOC container to have some functionality where if it can't resolve a dependency (i.e. an `ILogger`),  it should hook into the `IDependencyResolvingModule` implementation and ask for the dependency.

This way our library gets to use its choice of IOC Container, and the user's code has a way to resolve dependencies that its IOC container has no clue about. Wouldn't this solution work if IOC containers out there some how provided functionality to register singleton instances of any `IDependencyResolverModules` found in assemblies in the executing assembly's dir and when they can't resolve a type, ask any of the singleton modules?

But barring a solution that requires every other IOC container to accommodate, how else can this be solved? SO the problem in a few lines is, when a third party assembly chooses to use an IOC container for its internals, what is an easy solution such that this library can simply provide a mechanism for an IOC container sitting outside to hook into and resolve dependencies that live in the library.

Comment: Err... MyLibrary.SetLogger(ILogger logger) won't work?

Comment: the logging example is an oversimplified scenario I present to demonstrate the bidirectional dependency. the library I am working on has far more complex dependency resolution required to simply suffice with injecting dependencies via static methods as you demonstrate.

Comment: ok. my question is more on the lines of when a library warrants using its own IOC container, and the user has requirements that warrant they using their own IOC container, how can the two play well together.

Answer (score 3):

I see few possible approaches here:

1. Write default registrator for all of the popular IoC containers. Each of them should be placed in the separate assembly. Then developer can choose the one he needs and configure his container with it.
2. Define your own factory abstraction and write default implementation that will return the default logger. Let developer to substitute implementation of that factory. For example, with adapter for his favorite container. This approach is most container-agnostic, because developer can just use the default factory implementation. But this way  has nothing to do with auto-wiring.
3. The lazy variation of the first approach. Write small manual about configuring a container to work with default  implementations. Then developer could configure the container himself.
4. Combine all previous solutions to satisfy every developer. :)

EDIT: added example of integration of two containers

```
var allPublicInterfacesFromLibrary = typeof(AnyLibraryType)
    .Assembly.GetTypes()
    .Where(t => t.IsInterface && t.IsPublic);

foreach (var libraryInterface in allPublicInterfacesFromLibrary)
{
    var local = libraryInterface; //to prevent closure
    applicationContainer.Register(
        Component.For(libraryInterface)
        //delegate resolving
        .UsingFactoryMethod(k => libraryContainer.Resolve(local)) 
        //delegate lifetime management
        .LifestyleTransient() 
    );
}
```

Comment: Given a requirement the that library absolutely needs to use its choice of container, and the app consuming the library is also using an ioc container & no assumptions can be made that they are the same. With that in mind the solution will need to be on the lines of either extend the app's ioc container's resolving ability with a hook that plugs into the lib's ioc container, or find a way to register dependencies in the app's ioc container by resolving them from the library's ioc container. In both cases the lib's container will need to be registered as a singleton in the app's ioc container.

Comment: @afif, why the library itself depends on the ioc container? Only Composition Root should contain the reference to container. Only Application should contain the Composition Root. At library level you can just define some helpers to simplify library usage. Why not write configurators for popular containers and include them into library?

Comment: Read more about composition root: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx

Comment: with your first option, if you mean add support in the library to register types with all the popular containers, that invalidates the assumption that the library has the right to use the container that best suits its requirements. If the library has chosen a given container for its feature set, you are left with the pain of finding the equivalent of those features in all the other popular containers for adding support.

Comment: the library's types don't have any reference to a container. But there is a run time requirement on how these types are constructed, based on where are the extension points, based on what types can be overridden what parameters define how they are overridden at runtime.. basically the features that dictate how the library's object graph is constructed at runtime could lead the library to use its choice of IOC container that fulfils those requirements in the best manner.

Comment: Another example is the requirement to decorate an implementation to a given interface when requested at runtime based on different conventions. You can go to your choice of container based on how it does decoration when registering types to interfaces based on the context its provided at runtime. Requirements like these do not mean the container is being referenced inside classes a.k.a the Service locator anti pattern, but it does mean the library needs to go to its choice if container for building behaviour at runtime - and its perfectly warranted I believe.

Comment: I think library should be designed container-agnostic way. If you can apply the Poor Man's DI to it, it's should be possible to use the any container you want. Can you give an example of how the library depends on the container-specific features?

Comment: I have cited a few examples in my last two comments.

Comment: I don't recommend to use two containers parallel... it increases application complexity. But you can register the library's container as a factory for the library's types. So the application's container delegates composing of that types to the library's container. I don't recommend it, serious.

Comment: that's what I had in mind too. but mulling over if I'll need to register a factory for every type in the library or can it be done in one line for all types? can you demonstrate with a line of code for any popular container.